# Image uploading fails using html in bottle framework

Tags: python, html, mongodb, bottle, gridfs

I am creating a simple web application, where you can upload your article along with an image, using bottle framework. The HTML code for the upload page is:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/created" method="POST" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
            Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
            Body: <textarea rows = 10 name="body"></textarea><br>
            Choose image: <input type="file" name="image" ><br>
            <input type="submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to store the article in mongodb database and so, I want to store the image in GridFS. The bottle framework code for the same is:

```
@post("/created")
def created():
    connect = pymongo.MongoClient(server_address)
    db = connect.practiceB3
    articles = db.articles

    title = request.forms.get('title')
    body = request.forms.get('body')


    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    image = request.files.get('image')
    img_content = image.file.read()
    img_name = image.filename

    document = { "title":title,"body":body}

    articles.insert(document)

    fs.put(img_content,filename = img_name)
    return "Article successfully stored"
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error for the image section:

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/created.html' caused an error:

Internal Server Error

Exception:

AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file'",)

Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "blogger.py", line 70, in created
    img_content = image.file.read()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file'
```

I have run the exact same code on another machine and it worked perfectly. But on my laptop it fails. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's funny how in your code there is `img_content = image.file.read()` and your error is blaming `img_content = image.files.read()` ... notice the `s` ?

Comment: @Cyrbil Thanks for noticing that. I had accidentally uploaded the error that I was getting when I was doing an experiment to change 'file' to 'files' just in case to make sure that the later was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your error, if `request.files.get('image')` have no index `'image'`, it will return `None` (default behavior of `dict.get()`.

So the next line will fail `image.file.read()`.

Ensure your form do really send an image (with your browser webtools).

Comment: Thanks man. That helped. I checked whether the file was getting passed or not through firefox's web console and there I noticed that in my HTML form, it should have been enctype = multipart/form-data and not the one that I have typed above.